# formatting in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to display a set of data
in pivoted form

The data retrieved from query is in this format

```
AccID                Month                Year       FTE

1                     Jan                  2009       10
1                     Feb                  2009      20
2                     Jan                  2010      30
```

I want to display it as

```
AccID  Jan 2009  Feb 2009  Jan 2010       
1        10        20        
2                            30
```

Comment: XSLT is a technology for processing XML documents. Tabular (csv) data cannot be processed. You need to provide input in XML form.

Comment: If you want to use XSLT then please post the input in XML format, unless you want to use XSLT 2.0 and unparsed-text and tokenize to process plain text. But if you want to use XSLT 2.0 then please mention that explicitly as it makes things possible you can't achieve at all with pure XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kItemByDate" match="item" use="concat(Month,Year)"/>
    <xsl:key name="kItemByAccID" match="item" use="AccID"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vDates" 
         select="/root/item[count(.|key('kItemByDate',
                                        concat(Month,Year))[1])=1]"/>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>AccID</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="$vDates">
                    <th>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(Month,' ',Year)"/>
                    </th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[count(.|key('kItemByAccID',AccID)[1])=1]">
        <xsl:variable name="vItems" select="key('kItemByAccID',AccID)"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="AccID"/>
            </td>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vDates">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$vItems[Month=current()/Month]
                                                 [Year=current()/Year]
                                                 /FTE"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root>
    <item>
        <AccID>1</AccID>
        <Month>Jan</Month>
        <Year>2009</Year>
        <FTE>10</FTE>
    </item>
    <item>
        <AccID>1</AccID>
        <Month>Feb</Month>
        <Year>2009</Year>
        <FTE>20</FTE>
    </item>
    <item>
        <AccID>2</AccID>
        <Month>Jan</Month>
        <Year>2010</Year>
        <FTE>30</FTE>
    </item>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>AccID</th>
        <th>Jan 2009</th>
        <th>Feb 2009</th>
        <th>Jan 2010</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>30</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: HI Alejandro Thanks a LOT. WORKED UNBELIEVABLE